# leaflet plugin and leafletProxy

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I've added the leaflet [TextPath](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath) plugin to a shiny app in analogy to [this example](https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/8f6c8cc27597466351ad377e6774c30f). This works pretty well:

```
output$fullscreen_map <- renderLeaflet({
  points <- points_reactive()

  points %>%
    leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>%
    fitBounds(~min(lon), ~min(lat), ~max(lon), ~max(lat)) %>%
    registerPlugin(textPathPlugin) %>%
    onRender("function(el, x, data) {
                data = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(data);
                data = data.map(function(val) { return [val.lat, val.lon]; });
                var layer = L.polyline(data);
                layer.on('mouseover', function () {
                this.setText('  ►  ', {repeat: true, attributes: {fill: 'blue'}});
                });
                layer.on('mouseout', function () {
                this.setText(null);
                });
                layer.addTo(this);
    }", data = points)

})
```

In accordance with the [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) I would now like to use `leafletProxy()` so that the entire map doesn't get redrawn whenever the reactive data source changes. Alas, using the following snippet of code

```
leafletProxy("fullscreen_map", data = points) %>%
  onRender("function(el, x, data) {
              data = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(data);
              data = data.map(function(val) { return [val.lat, val.lon]; });
              var layer = L.polyline(data);
              layer.on('mouseover', function () {
              this.setText('  ►  ', {repeat: true, attributes: {fill: 'blue'}});
              });
              layer.on('mouseout', function () {
              this.setText(null);
              });
              layer.addTo(this);
  }", data = points)
```

does not work as intended. I assume this is because `onRender` is only called when a new render occurs and the whole point of `leafletProxy` is to not re-render? If this is correct, is there a way to do this using other methods?

Comment: This is an interesting problem... Shiny has pretty robust event handling, so I think the trick is to figure out the right place to tie in your script. It is a bit tricky to figure this out with out a WME. Would you mind posting one?

Comment: Seems to me like it should work. I wouldn't be surprised if a minor adjustment to the javascript fixed it, but would need to make a MWE and don't have the time right now.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your shiny server and running it again? I've had some terrible shiny problems over the past couple days that are inexplicable, but were solved by a restart. It's worth a shot.

Comment: @yosukesabai Would you please post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: yes yes, this evening i will do

Comment: Too much to post my code in comment, but I dont have any "solution". 
 So i just made new question. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846472/leaflet-plugin-and-leafletproxy-with-polylinedecorator-as-example

Comment: I came up with a solution in the Question above.  I continue to test out if that does what I wanted (let javascript plugin to work while I use leafletProxy)

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like below, although there would be more cleaner methods.

What I did was to use leafletProxy to add polylines layer from `points_reactive()` function, while setting group to be `reactive`.  I used listened to `layeradd` event of map, and if a layer with `reactive` group got added, i added the textPath.

```
output$fullscreen_map <- renderLeaflet({
  points <- points_reactive()

  points %>%
    leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>%
    fitBounds(~min(lon), ~min(lat), ~max(lon), ~max(lat)) %>%
    registerPlugin(textPathPlugin) %>%
    onRender("function(el, x, data) {
              var mymap = this;

              mymap.on('layeradd',
                function(e) {
                  console.log(e);
                  var layer = e.layer;

                  if (layer.groupname == 'reactive') {
                    layer.on('mouseover', function () {
                      this.setText('  ►  ', {repeat: true, attributes: {fill: 'blue'}});
                    });
                    layer.on('mouseout', function () {
                      this.setText(null);
                    });
                  }
                }
              );

            }", data = points)

  })

  observeEvent(input$clickme,{
               points <- points_reactive()

               leafletProxy('fullscreen_map') %>%
                 addPolylines(lng=points$lon, lat=points$lat, group='reactive')

  }
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say: active inputs and expressions that affect the renderLeaflet expression *will cause the entire map to be redrawn from scratch* and reset the map position and zoom level.

It sounds like you will have to dig deeper into Leaflet or trigger leafletProxy yourself, and make sure that the data source does not change, by using two data sources... (Perhaps "Proxy" is a misnomer here.)

Have a look and see if one of these plugins can help: https://leafletjs.com/plugins#dynamiccustom-data-loading

Comment: I attempted to understand how onrender works, and if i can update it to respond to other events.  `onRender` stores the code in `jsHooks[['render']]` of the widget.   See lines near here, function addHook as well. https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/blob/master/R/htmlwidgets.R#L155 .  And then this stored code is processed in javascript code, two locations in inst/www/htmlwidgets.js https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/blob/master/inst/www/htmlwidgets.js .  I thought another call to `evalAndRun` would do from somewhere in the js code may do, but cannot move beyond from here...

Comment: Is this the right direction?  Still need to learn how this entire shiny system works, i am total novice for these interactive tool development...