# Can't get Leaflet.Spin plugin working in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I have a shiny app which involves drawing a large number of lines on a map. I would like to use a spinner to show the user that rendering is underway. Most shiny approaches don't work because they only show the spinner while the data is being sent to leaflet, not when leaflet is rendering. The Leaflet.Spin plugin looks promising but I have been struggling to get it to work. The examples I have been following are

https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92

[leaflet plugin and leafletProxy with polylineDecorator as Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846472/leaflet-plugin-and-leafletproxy-with-)

How do I get the js events to fire properly and show Leaflet.Spin when the lines (circles in this example) are rendering? Thanks!

## Update: Spinner now works, but events fire for each individual circle added, so if number of circles declines, spinner doesn't turn off correctly.

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools) # for htmlDependency
library(htmlwidgets) # for onRender

# https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846472/leaflet-plugin-and-leafletproxy-with-polylinedecorator-as-example
spinPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "spin.js", 
  "2.3.2",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.3.2"),
  script = "spin.min.js") # there's no spin.css

leafletspinPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "Leaflet.Spin", 
  "1.1.2",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.Spin/1.1.2"),
  script = "leaflet.spin.min.js")

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}

# Note: Ctrl-Shift-J opens the javascript console in the browser
spin_event <- "function(el, x) {
  console.log('spin event added'); 
  var mymap = this;
  mymap.on('layerremove', function(e) {
    console.log('layerremove fired');
    mymap.spin(true);
  });
  mymap.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    console.log('layeradd fired');
    mymap.spin(false); 
  });
}"

dlat <- 1 / 111000 * 100 # degrees per metre

ui <- fluidRow(
  tags$h2("Using Leaflet.Spin in Shiny"),
  actionButton("plotbutton", label = "Show Spinner While Adding Markers"),
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    cat("renderLeaflet\n")
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(175.322, -37.789, zoom = 17) %>% 
      registerPlugin(spinPlugin) %>% 
      registerPlugin(leafletspinPlugin) %>% 
      onRender(spin_event) %>% 
      clearShapes() %>% # initialise spinner
      addCircles(
        lng = 175.322,
        lat = -37.789,
        radius = 0,
        opacity = 0
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$plotbutton, {
    cat("input$plotbutton\n")
    n <- ceiling(runif(1) * 10000)
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>% 
      addCircles(
        lng = 175.322 + (runif(n) * 2 - 1) * dlat * 6,
        lat = -37.789 + (runif(n) * 2 - 1) * dlat * 1.5,
        radius = dlat * runif(n) * dlat
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One year late, but I was looking for a way to have a busy spinner for leaflet.

I realized that your original code would create x number of spin instances on `clearShapes()`. If the following `addCircles()` has less than x number of circles, there would be spin instances left running.

My solution is to use a dummy layer to watch for from Javascript. In the example below, a circle with `layerId = 'spinnerMarker'`. To start the `leafletproxy` update, that layer is removed with `removeShape(layerId = 'spinnerMarker')` which triggers JS `layerremove`. The data circles are then added. The update is ended by adding a circle with `layerId = 'spinnerMarker'` to trigger the JS `layeradd`.

In JS, the layer being added or removed is checked with `e.layer.options.layerId == 'spinnerMarker'` to run `mymap.spin()`.

This way there is only one spin instance running.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools) # for htmlDependency
library(htmlwidgets) # for onRender

# https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846472/leaflet-plugin-and-leafletproxy-with-polylinedecorator-as-example
spinPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "spin.js", 
  "2.3.2",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.3.2"),
  script = "spin.min.js") # there's no spin.css

leafletspinPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "Leaflet.Spin", 
  "1.1.2",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.Spin/1.1.2"),
  script = "leaflet.spin.min.js")

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}

# Note: Ctrl-Shift-J opens the javascript console in the browser
spin_event <- "function(el, x) {
  console.log('spin event added'); 
  var mymap = this;
  mymap.on('layerremove', function(e) {
    console.log('layerremove fired');
    if (e.layer.options.layerId == 'spinnerMarker') {
      console.log(e.layer.options.layerId);
      mymap.spin(true);
    }
  });
  mymap.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    console.log('layeradd fired');
    if (e.layer.options.layerId == 'spinnerMarker') {
      console.log(e.layer.options.layerId);
      mymap.spin(false);
    }
  });
}"

dlat <- 1 / 111000 * 100 # degrees per metre

ui <- fluidRow(
  tags$h2("Using Leaflet.Spin in Shiny"),
  actionButton("plotbutton", label = "Show Spinner While Adding Markers"),
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    cat("renderLeaflet\n")
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(175.322, -37.789, zoom = 17) %>% 
      registerPlugin(spinPlugin) %>% 
      registerPlugin(leafletspinPlugin) %>% 
      onRender(spin_event) %>% 
      clearShapes() %>% # initialise spinner
      addCircles(     # invisible placeholder
        lng = 175.322,
        lat = -37.789,
        radius = 0,
        opacity = 0,
        layerId = 'spinnerMarker'   # identifier, can be found in js: e.layer.options.layerId
      )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plotbutton, {
    cat("input$plotbutton\n")
    n <- ceiling(runif(1) * 10000)
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      removeShape(layerId = 'spinnerMarker') %>%    # this triggers mymap.spin(true)
      clearShapes() %>% 
      addCircles(
        lng = 175.322 + (runif(n) * 2 - 1) * dlat * 6,
        lat = -37.789 + (runif(n) * 2 - 1) * dlat * 1.5,
        radius = dlat * runif(n) * dlat
      ) %>%
      addCircles(         # invisible placeholder to trigger the mymap.spin(false)
        lng = 175.322,
        lat = -37.789,
        radius = 0,
        opacity = 0,
        layerId = 'spinnerMarker'   # identifier, can be found in js: e.layer.options.layerId
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You’re welcome. I believe there’s a better way of doing this using leaflet r’s `invokeMethod()` instead of leaflet js’ `layeradd`.

Comment: So  this method works by adding an extra invisible shape attached to the spinner, which gets plotted in sequence with other shapes. Nice!

Comment: Yes, a hacky way of doing it, I admit. Apparently, each shape is one layer. So, if your `addCircles()` has 1000 elements, that's 1000 layers. Leafletjs `layeradd` method is triggered 1000 times. `clearShapes()` removes those 1000 layers. Leafletjs `layerremove` is triggered 1000 times creating 1000 instances of the spinner. Then you draw 500 circles which only clears 500 spinners. By watching only that one invisible shape, we only ever have one spinner running.

Comment: @SimonWoodward, I've continued working on the Spinner. Don't need an invisible object anymore. I have written it as a plugin and submitting it to `leaflet.extras2`. If you want a peek, https://github.com/radbasa/leaflet.extras2/tree/spin

Comment: The Spin plugin has been incorporated into `leaflet.extras2`. https://github.com/trafficonese/leaflet.extras2

Comment: @rbasa Wow, your code in leaflet.extras2 works perfectly for me. Have been looking for a solution for this problem for nearly a year now. SimonWoodward and rbasa, thanks for all the effort you put into this

Answer (score 2):

The URLs you provide are not valid. Try

```
spinPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "spin.js", 
  "4.1.0",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.3.2"),
  script = "spin.min.js") # there's no spin.css

leafletspinPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "Leaflet.Spin", 
  "1.1.2",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.Spin/1.1.2"),
  script = "leaflet.spin.min.js")
```

Comment: @SimonWoodward What does not work ? You mean the spinner doesn't go away after the circles are added ?

Comment: The spinner does not appear at all. Does my reprex work for you?

Comment: @SimonWoodward Yes it works, but I reduced the number of circles to 1000.

Comment: Thanks, this solve one problem, but still having problems with the events as as explained above.

Comment: Stephane Laurent are you able to help with the event trigger problem above? I've put a bounty on it now. Thanks.